# How to add the docker IP address to the container while starting it?

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm bringing up the container in bridge mode and need to check the ip address which is in the docker bridge network.

docker-compose:

```
 test:
    image:  test:latest 
    network_mode: bridge   
    ports:
      - '444:8443'
    privileged: yes
    ulimits:
      core: -1
    environment:
      EULA: "yes"
    volumes:
      - /var/test.conf:/var/test.conf
```

Please suggest how can I add this docker ip address to the container while staring it ?
As some of the configuration is dependent on the docker ip address.

Comment: If you're doing in-network reference to the container, you could set the container's name and then use the container name instead of its IP.

Comment: I tried with this docker compose and added container_name, i tried echo $test but it didn't showed the docker ip details, can you please correct the configuration ?  I need to add the required configuration in container with this docker ip address so looking for a way: ``` test:
    image:  test:latest 
    network_mode: bridge 
    container_name: test  
    ports:
      - '444:8443'
    privileged: yes
    ulimits:
      core: -1
    environment:
      EULA: "yes"
    volumes:
      - /var/test.conf:/var/test.conf```

Comment: Try running this in your container:   awk 'END{print $1}' /etc/hosts

Comment: I tried but I need to add this docker ip address to the container in docker-compose itself while staring it. there are some  configuration which is dependent on the docker ip address which i will be adding as a variable in configuration file.

Comment: If the awk works, you can try using the result as a command line argument for the program you are starting.